# Notification build showing title and imge but not content

Tags: java, android, firebase, push-notification

I'm pushing notification to my clients who have installed my app with as Data paylod with image, title and content. It works well but content is not blank. I even replaced content with title and also with  dummy text instead from server  but still content field is blank.  So I'm sure I'm getting content field also but there must be some problem in my code itself.

Here  is my code

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
            .setContentTitle(Config.title)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSound)
            .setContentText(Config.content)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setStyle(style)
            .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);


    notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

and my method to push data is

```
{
    "data": {
        "title": "Check our New Recipe",
        "content" : "Check Out This Awesome Game!",
        "imageUrl": "http://h5.4j.com/thumb/Ninja-Run.jpg"
    },
    "to": "/topics/food"
}
```

Also I repalce

```
 .setContentText(Config.content)
```

with

```
 .setContentText("This is my content")
```

but still it is invisible.

The tutorial I followed is

https://android.jlelse.eu/android-push-notification-using-firebase-and-advanced-rest-client-3858daff2f50

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to show your content and image

```
private void sendNotification(String messageBody, Context context) {
        Log.e("rsp", messageBody);

        String title = "Notification";
        String desciption = messageBody;

        Intent intent = null;

        try {
            JSONObject message = new JSONObject(messageBody);
            title = message.getString("title");
            desciption = message.getString("msg");
            intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = null;
        final int NOTIFY_ID = 0; // ID of notification
        String id = "mychannel"; // default_channel_id

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        if (notifManager == null) {
            notifManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
            NotificationChannel mChannel = notifManager.getNotificationChannel(id);
            if (mChannel == null) {
                mChannel = new NotificationChannel(id, title, importance);
                mChannel.enableVibration(true);
                mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
                notifManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
            }

            builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, id)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(desciption)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
        } else {
            builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, id);
            intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            builder.setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(desciption)                            // required
                    .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_popup_reminder)   // required
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setTicker("Accept your request")
                    .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400})
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
        }

        Notification notification = builder.build();
        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, notification);
    }
```

You can read complete code here:[Firebase push notification](https://trinitytuts.com/firebase-push-notification-android/)